# How to open electron app using shortcut key?

Tags: node.js, macos, desktop-application, electron, keyboard-shortcuts

I have an electron app working on Mac OS, But once the app is moved to Applications , then I want to have shortcut key to launch directly without double clicking every time.

Like Command+KEY [Any key combination]
Even this should also work for Windows

Answer (score 3):

You can use electron's [globalShortcut module](https://electronjs.org/docs/tutorial/keyboard-shortcuts#global-shortcuts) to detect keyboard events even when the application does not have keyboard focus.

In this example, the app opens a browser window when `Control+X` or `Command+X` is pressed and prevents quitting when the window is closed to contiunue listening for shortcut in background.

```
// require Electron
const { app, BrowserWindow, globalShortcut } = require('electron')

function createWindow () {
  // Create the browser window.
  let win = new BrowserWindow({
    width: 800,
    height: 600,
    webPreferences: {
      nodeIntegration: true
    }
  })

  // and load the index.html of the app.
  win.loadFile('index.html')
}

// when app is ready register a global shortcut
// that calls createWindow function
app.on('ready', () => {
    globalShortcut.register('CommandOrControl+X', createWindow)
})

// do not quit when all windows are closed
// and continue running on background to listen
// for shortcuts
app.on('window-all-closed', (e) => {
  e.preventDefault()
  e.returnValue = false
})
```

If you want to launch the app on startup, you can use [this package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/auto-launch).

Comment: Is it possible to show the existing window instead of running createWindow instead?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know electron doesn't support shortcut key to open an electron application, because if the application is not running, so doesn't electron.

Therefore what you are looking for cannot be provided out of the box. In OSX you have `automator` and in this page you can follow the steps to create shortcut for opening the app.

[How to Launch Any App with a Keyboard Shortcut](http://computers.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-launch-any-app-with-a-keyboard-shortcut--mac-31463)

In Windows 10 you can just modify the properties of the .exe and there you will find an option called `Shortcut Key`. In this webpage you can see the steps:

[Open programs with keyboard shortcuts in Windows 10](http://www.cnet.com/how-to/open-programs-with-keyboard-shortcuts-in-windows-10/)