# Define a keyboard shortcut to start an Electron.js app with Node

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron, keyboard-shortcuts, desktop-application

I'm building an Electron app and I want the user to be able to open the app within a button click, using a keyboard shortcut. I want to set the shortcut automatically in the code.

It should work after the user closed the app and after a computer startup.

I've tried this [how-to-open-electron-app-using-shortcut-key](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59407418/13273317)
, and it works if the user run the app and closed the app already, but it won't work after a computer reset because the Electron process stoped, and when I clicked the shortcut more then onse, the app buttons stopping to work until I left with only one window open.

Is there another way to implement that? Maybe a process that listening to the specific key and runs whenever the computer is on?

Comment: Use [auto-launch](https://www.npmjs.com/package/auto-launch) to run a [global-shortcuts](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/tutorial/keyboard-shortcuts#global-shortcuts) script, at startup. Without a decent code attempt at solving the issue, your question is *off-topic* here. For details, please read [ask].